# Using eclipse connect to hdp but" Cannot read the array length because "jobs" is null"

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm use eclipse on Windows to connect hadoop on Vmware to run map reduce.
First, I installed hadoop-eclipse-plugin.
Then,I download /usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/hadoop from Vmware,put it into eclipse's perfenence
Finally,i created a connection but failed.

An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater".
Cannot read the array length because "jobs" is null

By the way,My local jdk is 17 and hadoop version is 2.6.5

I examine my port, it is same as core-site.xml.
So have no idea about this
I want to get some suggestions and help:)